# How do you attach Vue.js events on dynamic elements added with jQuery.append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Laravel & Vue.js. When I append some elements to page and change DOM using jQuery the Vue.js, events like `@click` & `@blur` will not work.

Is there any method to update DOM?

```js
dropzone_success(file, response) {

$('.dz-details').append('<button type="button" class="thumb_button" id="'+response.path+'" @click="somemethod($event)">Make Default</button>');

}
```

And my method for example:

```js
somemethod(event)
{
     console.log(event.target);
}
```

Comment: In the first place why you required to append something using `jquery` when using `vue`. Vue follows a lifecycle and bind elements to provide reactivity if you add something externally after mounting will not be recognized by `vue` instance and none of the properties will work.

Comment: ok how can i add some element using vue?? it is DropzoneJs Success method a im adding a button to every picture thumbnail i uploaded and every button has an id which contains the picture uploaded location and when user click on the button, is want to make that picture to default picture

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-dropzone look at this and add to your `vue` component. Avoid using `jquery`.

Comment: @Satyam Pathak im using this package

Comment: Can you share your component code ?

Comment: template(){
            return `<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
                <div class="dz-image">
                    <div data-dz-thumbnail-bg></div>
                    <button type="button" v-on:click="this.testfu($event)">test</button>
                </div>

        `;
        },

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't probably be using Vue.js with jQuery in the first place, as they work in a much different concept. The following should give you some rough idea how this could be done in Vue.js alone:

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      dropzone: {},
      dropzoneOpts: {
        // ...
      },

      responsePath: ''
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.dropzone = new Dropzone('#dropzone_id', {
      ...this.dropzoneOpts,
      success: this.dropzone_success
    });
  },

  methods: {
    dropzone_success(file, response) {
      this.responsePath = response.path;
    },

    somemethod(evt) {
      // ...
    }
  }
});
```

```vue
<div class="dz-details">
  <button 
    v-if="responsePath" 
    :id="responsePath" 
    class="thumb_button"
    @click="somemethod">Make Default</button>
</div>
```

The point is, you don't do direct DOM manipulation with Vue.js as this framework is really building virtual DOM instead of the real DOM, it supports conditional rendering, two-way data binding, etc.

Check out this nice article on [Declarative and Imperative programming](https://codeburst.io/declarative-vs-imperative-programming-a8a7c93d9ad2).